# What does the "skipUncaughtErrors" flag mean by server?

Tags: testing, automation, automated-tests, e2e-testing, testcafe

In the [TestCafe documentation](https://devexpress.github.io/testcafe/documentation/reference/configuration-file.html#skipuncaughterrors) the `skipUncaughtErrors` flag mentions: `uncaught error or unhandled promise rejection occurs on the server during test execution`.

What is meant by `server` here?

I found this flag after we started getting an issue quite randomly, with very little to debug from:

```
    1) - Error in fixture.beforeEach hook -
       Unhandled promise rejection:
 
       Error: [eval("")] Not JSON response
       at exports.newError
```

Figured it was worth a try to set `skipUncaughtErrors: true` and we haven't seen that issue since. Nonetheless, the team is worried about using features we don't understand. :)

Answer (score 2):

The `server` word here means a NodeJS process where test code is executed. So, any uncaught error or unhandled promise rejection that occurred in test code will be ignored by TestCafe if the `skipUncaughtErrors` option is enabled. For more details about TestCafe architecture, refer to the following topic in the TestCafe documentation: https://devexpress.github.io/testcafe/documentation/how-it-works/#client-server-architecture